# Filter one table based on another in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with the following columns:

Authors

```
id | name | age
```

Books

```
authorId | title | pages
```

I need to somehow get top five of the author names who have books with more than 200 pages. I experimented with some types of joins and subqueries and this was my best shot:

```
SELECT 
    author.name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE pages > 200 AND 'books.authorId' = 'author.id') AS PageCount 
FROM 
    authors AS author 
ORDER BY 
    PageCount DESC
```

Unfortunately, it returns `PageCount` as 0.

What would be the way to get the needed result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inner join, count, and group by instead of a subquery:

```
    SELECT  au.name, COUNT(*) PageCount
    FROM    authors AS au
    INNER JOIN books ON  "books"."authorId" = au.id 
    WHERE  books.pages > 200 
    GROUP BY au.name
    ORDER BY PageCount DESC
```

Don't use single quotes around column names. If you need to, use backticks instead. Single quotes  are for literal strings, not for column names.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't seem to confirm this is working because my select query fails with `column books.authorId does not exist`. My `author.id` is set as a primary key and `books.authorId` is a foreign key. Both of these are of type UUID. Is that the reason?

Comment: no  ..  books.authorId  .. is mentioned in your table schema  ..  so be sure that the column name you have in you query match really your columns name  ..

Comment: I know it sounds strange, but that's exactly what I'm doing. Here's [my query](https://i.imgur.com/1UxpDRc.png) in a Heroku Postgres instance. Backticks don't help either. Feels like something's wrong with my models.

Comment: try use quote around table.column  as  "books.authorId"  and be sure for right capitalized  characters matching

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that as well, but it gives me pretty much the [same error](https://i.imgur.com/Try1B8s.png).

Comment: try using books.authorid  or books.author_id

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work :( I guess I should probably redo the whole schema and start from scratch. No idea why this is happening.

Comment: `"books.authorId"` needs to be `"books"."authorId"`